# Failed building wheel for pycocotools

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I am exploring YOLO-NAS onject detection, in which I have to install super gradient module, it gives the erorr like this

The commmand which I am entering to download is
`!pip install super-gradients==3.1.0`

which gives:

`error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ [end of output]`

`note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip. ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycocotools, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

`Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml): started Building wheel for pycocotools (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error' Failed to build pycocotools`

Comment: Read the error messages: they are there for a reason. This one says: "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required". Did you get the Microsoft C++ Build Tools"?

Comment: @9769953, I did install that as well, after that it again gives me the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while installing it on Colab notebook.
I tried this:

```
!pip install super-gradients
```

Ans:

```
-> Collecting super-gradients
Downloading super_gradients-3.2.0
```

Worked!

Answer (score 0):

It's all about version error
python version:

> 3.7 > valid version < 3.10

super_gradients version

> valid version >= 3.2.0

If you use super-gradients version lower than 3.2.0 Building wheel for 'pycocotools' will fail

If you use python version upper than  3.9 Building wheel for 'onnx-tools' will fail